# PHP not showing all fields from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying a MySQL database from PHP.

```
global $pdo;
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT D.RecordID, Info.StudentName, Info.StudentNumber, D.StatusCode, D.CommMethod, D.AbsenceType, D.AbsenceCode, tblclosuretypes.StatusDescription
FROM
(SELECT vstudentlist.StudentName, vstudentlist.StudentNumber from vstudentlist" . (($classnum!='')?" WHERE vstudentlist.ClassNum=".$classnum:'') . ") Info
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT tblschoolattendancedata.RecordID, tblschoolattendancedata.StudentNumber, tblschoolattendancedata.AttendanceDate, tblschoolattendancedata.StatusCode, tblschoolattendancedata.CommMethod, tblschoolattendancedata.AbsenceType, tblschoolattendancedata.AbsenceCode
FROM tblschoolattendancedata WHERE AttendanceDate = '" . $attdate . "') D
ON Info.StudentNumber = D.StudentNumber
LEFT JOIN tblclosuretypes ON D.StatusCode = tblclosuretypes.StatusCode ORDER BY Info.StudentName;";
//echo $sql;
$res = $pdo->query($sql);
$count = 1;
if($res->rowCount() > 0){
    while($result = $res->fetch()){
        echo 
        "<tr>
        <td>",$result[0],"</td>
        <td>",$result[1],"</td>
        <td>",$result[2],"</td>
        <td>",$result[3],"</td>
        <td>",$result[4],"</td>
        <td>",$result[5],"</td>
        <td>",$result[6],"</td>
        <td>",$result[7],"</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

I've tested the query in Workbench and it returns the desired results

```
RecordID    StudentName  StudentNumber  StatusCode CommMethod  AbsenceType AbsenceCode StatusDescription
44154_0026  Student 1        26             D          1            
44154_0112  Student 2        112            D          1            
44154_0080  Student 3        80             D          1            
44154_0104  Student 4        104            D          1            
44154_0009  Student 5         9             D          1            
44154_0071  Student 6         71            D          1            
44154_0084  Student 7         84            D          1            
44154_0096  Student 8         96            D          1            
44154_0003  Student 9          3            D          1            
44154_0093  Student 10        93            D          1
```

(The last three fields are blank.  This was expected).

If I echo the query in PHP and paste it into Workbench, I get the expected result as well.

However, the HTML table only shows the first 3 fields for all ten rows.  The fourth and fifth fields (StatusCode, CommMethod) are blank.  I don't get any PHP errors and the code seems to be running to completion (again, it produces the expected number of rows).  I tested that the correct number of fields were being returned from the query with `$res->columnCount()` and got a value of 8, as expected.

I'm wondering why it is only showing the values for the first three fields in each record.

var_dump for first two query rows:

```
array(16) { 
    ["RecordID"]=> string(10) "44154_0026" 
    [0]=> string(10) "44154_0026" 
    ["StudentName"]=> string(14) "Andre Switenki" 
    [1]=> string(14) "Andre Switenki" 
    ["StudentNumber"]=> string(2) "26" 
    [2]=> string(2) "26" 
    ["StatusCode"]=> NULL 
    [3]=> NULL 
    ["CommMethod"]=> NULL 
    [4]=> NULL 
    ["AbsenceType"]=> NULL 
    [5]=> NULL 
    ["AbsenceCode"]=> NULL 
    [6]=> NULL 
    ["StatusDescription"]=> NULL 
    [7]=> NULL } 
array(16) { ["RecordID"]=> string(10) "44154_0112" [0]=> string(10) "44154_0112" ["StudentName"]=> string(15) "Erick Macedonio" [1]=> string(15) "Erick Macedonio" ["StudentNumber"]=> string(3) "112" [2]=> string(3) "112" ["StatusCode"]=> NULL [3]=> NULL ["CommMethod"]=> NULL [4]=> NULL ["AbsenceType"]=> NULL [5]=> NULL ["AbsenceCode"]=> NULL [6]=> NULL ["StatusDescription"]=> NULL [7]=> NULL }
```

I can see that the StatusCode and CommMethod fields are returning NULL.  Question is why are they coming back NULL when I am to echo the query, paste it into Workbench and get results for those fields.

Comment: You have quoting problems in your `echo` statement, you should be getting a syntax error.

Comment: Since the script is running, the actual code must be different from what you posted.

Comment: typos in the echo statement are from transposing into SO.  Actual echo statement in code is correct.  Again, the issue is that I'm not getting all of the fields to appear in the table - i.e. $result[3] and $result[4], aren't giving me the expected value.  Even tried echoing just those values (separately) and they are blank.

Comment: Please show us the results of `var_dump($result);`.

Comment: The var_dump and workbench are showing different student names for the same id. Are you sure you are connecting to the same db?

Comment: You have null values in the results.

Comment: Those will turn into blank values in the output.

Comment: Please show the results of `echo $sql;`.

Comment: Start with something simpler and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in your `echo` line, due to incorrect mixing of quotes, commas, and semicolons.

But since you're echoing all the columns in order, you can use `implode()` to join them rather than listing them explicitly.

```
echo "<tr>\n<td>" . implode("</td>\n<td>", $result) . "</td>\n<tr>";
```

And if you want to use this method, you should use `$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)`, otherwise you'll get every column duplicated.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't see the vales from all the query fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems might be on quotes. Use this way.

```
"<tr>
    <td>".$result[0]."</td>
    <td>".$result[1]."</td>
    <td>".$result[2]."</td>
    <td>".$result[3]."</td>
    <td>".$result[4]."</td>
    <td>".$result[5]."</td>
    <td>".$result[6]."</td>
    <td>".$result[7]."</td>
    </tr>";
```